# Postgresql - Update CTE result from CTE Output?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I need to update CTE o/p one of the column value (top 1 record) based on the latest timestamp & then return.

Query

```
WITH cte AS (
select
    dt_zone.zone_name,
    dt_material_status.mtstatus_name,
    dt_historicalzone.visit_time_in
FROM ((public.dt_historicalzone 
    INNER JOIN dt_material_status
        ON dt_historicalzone.mtstatus_id = dt_material_status.mtstatus_id)
    INNER JOIN dt_zone ON dt_historicalzone.zone_id = dt_zone.zone_id)
    WHERE material_id = 'ELS46885' 
    ORDER BY dt_historicalzone.zone_id DESC)

UPDATE cte SET cte.mtstatus_name = true WHERE SELECT * FROM cte LIMIT 1;
SELECT * FROM cte
```

Comment: CTEs ain't no tables.. You cannot update them. They are just like a view only presenting data. Perhaps you need to rewrite your select or you could save and modify the data in a temporary table.

Comment: Anyways what is your DMBS? You have tagged two of them, but they are not the same for sure

Comment: Are you using Postgres or SQL Server?  CTEs are not updatable in Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

when you update a CTE, the background table is getting updated. You can have only one statement below CTE. Post that CTE loses its scope. You can only go for UPDATE statement, post CTE. I have modified the CTE and updated the top 1 row.

The above statement is applicable for SQL Server. In Postgres, the CTE cannot be target of UPDATE statements. See the below error in Postgres.

> Query Error: error: relation "cte" cannot be the target of a modifying
>   statement

```
WITH cte AS (
select top 1
    dt_zone.zone_name,
    dt_material_status.mtstatus_name,
    dt_historicalzone.visit_time_in
FROM public.dt_historicalzone 
    INNER JOIN dt_material_status
        ON dt_historicalzone.mtstatus_id = dt_material_status.mtstatus_id
    INNER JOIN dt_zone ON dt_historicalzone.zone_id = dt_zone.zone_id
    WHERE material_id = 'ELS46885' 
    ORDER BY dt_historicalzone.zone_id DESC)
UPDATE cte
SET mtstatus_name = true
```

I have tried with sample data for a CTE update. Below works fine in SQL Server.

```
create table #test(a int)
create table #test2(a int, b int)

insert into #test values (1)
insert into #test2 values (1,1)

;WITH CTE as
(
select top 1 t.a, t2.b
FROM #test as t
join #test2 as t2
on t.a = t2.a
order by t.a desc
)
update cte set b = 0 

select * from #test2
```

Comment: I downvoted because the OP's question title includes "Postgresql" and also the `LIMIT` syntax implies Postgres is being used, and not SQL Server.  Note that it isn't possible in Postgres to update a CTE directly, so your code won't even run.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, sorry. I have updated my answer. I saw SQL Server also in the tag and went ahead with the answer. I should have taken care.

Comment: I removed the downvote, maybe I'm wrong, but the OP looks to be in Postgres :-)

Comment: You can chain CTEs

Answer (score 1):

You may try using an update join, with Postgres' syntax, including a CTE for the limit portion of the query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT dh.mtstatus_id
    FROM dt_historicalzone dh
    INNER JOIN dt_zone dz
        ON dh.zone_id = dz.zone_id
    ORDER BY zone_id DESC
    LIMIT 1
)

UPDATE dt_material_status d
SET mtstatus_name = true
FROM cte t
WHERE d.mtstatus_id = t.mtstatus_id AND
      d.material_id = 'ELS46885';
```